# PushNotification não fecha [Android Wear]

Tags: android, push-notification

Meu projeto possui vários tipos de notificações. Criei um ENUM onde guardo o tipo e o id da Notificação.

```
final Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
intent.putExtra(TYPE, NotificationType.TYPE1.type);
intent.setFlags(  Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
final PendingIntent open = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, NotificationType.TYPE1.idNotification, 
intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Já na `MainActivity`, invoco o cancel passando o id conforme o tipo:

```
String tipo = extras.getString(NotificationService.TYPE);
if(NotificationService.NotificationType.TYPE1.type.equals(tipo)){
    NotificationManager.class.cast(this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE)).cancel(NotificationService.NotificationType.TYPE1.idNotification);
}
```

No Smartphone, ele remove corretamente, mas no Wear, ainda continua aberta! Se clico novamente no Wear (de alguma já fechado no smartphone) ele exibe uma mensagem de Não Funcionou!

Alguém sabe se posso forçar a encerrar no Wear?

Existe outra forma de cancelar uma Notificação?